# How to export image from Air app directly into a powerpoint slide programmatically

Tags: windows, vb.net, apache-flex, flash, powerpoint

Apologies if this has been answered before or if it's too obvious - pointers are greatly appreciated if this is the case.

What I'm trying to do:
1) have a way to save / copy screenshot from an Air app
2) automatically paste such screenshot into a new powerpoint slide in the current presentation

I have part 1 down but have no idea on how to do part 2 - I have very little experience with programming around MS apps.

thank you.

f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read the screen into a bitmap, then encode the bitmap into a JPG or PNG, write the encoded image to a temporary location and then copy the encoded image file location to the system clipboard.  That will then allow you to paste it in PowerPoint.  You can see some example code that does the Clipboard stuff here:
http://code.google.com/p/air-quick-fix/source/browse/trunk/AIRQuickFixClient/src/QuickFix.mxml?r=7

Check out the documentation on the Clipboard class here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html